# Disabled is not working in Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to use `disabled` on a material form input :

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input 
    matInput 
    formControlName="date" 
    [matDatepicker]="dp3" 
    placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle 
    matSuffix 
    [for]="dp3">
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

My form control is defined as follow:

```
this.dateAmountFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  date: new FormControl({
    value: '',
    disabled: true
  }),
});
```

However, when clicking on the `input` field, it is not getting **disabled**.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using `disabled="false"` in `<mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>`

That's why the form field is not getting disabled.

You might want to change your implementation like this:

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="dateAmountFormGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input 
      matInput 
      [matDatepicker]="picker1" 
      placeholder="Angular forms" 
      formControlName="date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle 
      matSuffix 
      [for]="picker1">
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Class:

```
export class DatepickerValueExample {
  ...
  dateAmountFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.dateAmountFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      date: new FormControl({
        value: new Date(),
        disabled: true
      }),
    });
    ...
  }

  ...

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-radio-disabled?file=app/datepicker-value-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: Simple solution, great! Any reason for adding the whole code examples, since it's just one line he has to change? That and the StackBlitz link would be totally sufficient imho.

Comment: Just for a hypothetical situation if the StackBlitz Sample Link breaks or doesn't work in the near future. I've seen this happening with Plunkr links that end up being useless.